# Radio Button with displayed incremental percentage values with seek bar

Tags: android, eclipse

I need help with class codes that will enable layout containing radio buttons to display incremental or decremental values when a radio button is selected and the seek bar is used to increase or decrease its assigned values from 0 to 100.Please Help!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="21dp"
    android:text="Heat" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="3dp"
    android:layout_y="66dp"
    android:text="Smoke" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="3dp"
    android:layout_y="164dp"
    android:text="Aerosol" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="3dp"
    android:layout_y="114dp"
    android:text="Scattered Lights" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="212dp"
    android:text="Benzene" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="172dp"
    android:layout_y="170dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="171dp"
    android:layout_y="223dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="170dp"
    android:layout_y="122dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="169dp"
    android:layout_y="72dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="167dp"
    android:layout_y="28dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="287dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="15dp"
    android:layout_y="277dp" />
```

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: i have added the layout xml codes above.